# Python program to number rows

Tags: python

i have a file with data as such.

```
>1_DL_2021.1123
>2_DL_2021.1206
>3_DL_2021.1202
>3_DL_2021.1214
>4_DL_2021.1214
>4_DL_2021.1214
>6_DL_2021.1214
>7_DL_2021.1214
>8_DL_2021.1214
```

now as you can see the data is not numbered properly and hence needs to be numbered.
what im aiming for is this:

```
>1_DL_2021.1123
>2_DL_2021.1206
>3_DL_2021.1202
>4_DL_2021.1214
>5_DL_2021.1214
>6_DL_2021.1214
>7_DL_2021.1214
>8_DL_2021.1214
>9_DL_2021.1214
```

now the file has a lot of other stuff between these lines starting with > sign. i want only the > sign stuff affected.

could someone please help me out with this.
also there are 563 such lines so manually doing it is out of question.

Comment: Try this approach: Read the file line by line. Have a counter that starts at 1 (`c = 1`) Check whether the first character is `>`. If this is the case change the second character to `c`. Increase `c` by one (`c += 1`).

Comment: @AakifRehman your lines have no difference in what you want and what you got. Provide actual difference please

Comment: @sudden_appearance there's a difference in the second character - in the second example they're numbered correctly.

Comment: @sudden_appearance Look at the number at the beginning of each line. The goal is that those numbers are increasing by one from line to line. In the provided first case some numbers (for example 3) are repeated.

Comment: @Blupper, how do i ger rid of the characters between the > and the _

Comment: Sure, now i got it

Comment: @AakifRehman Let's say you have a line as a string in the variable `line`. Use split to separate this string: The part before the first `_`: `line.split('_',1)[0]`. The part after the first `_`:  `line.split('_',1)[1]`

Comment: @Blupper i am some what new to python coding and .split() always manages to really confuse me and hence i would request you to kindly write a piece of code for me if time and situation allow you.

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming input data file is "input.txt"

You can achieve what you want with this

```
import re

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    a = f.readlines()

regex = re.compile(r"^>\d+_DL_2021\.\d+\n$")

counter = 1

for i, line in enumerate(a):
    if regex.match(line):
        tokens = line.split("_")
        tokens[0] = f">{counter}"
        a[i] = "_".join(tokens)

        counter += 1

with open("input.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(a)
```

So what it does it searches for line with the regex `^>\d+_DL_2021\.\d+\n$`, then splits it by `_` and gets the first (0th) element and rewrites it, then counts up by 1 and continues the same thing, after all it just writes updated strings back to "input.txt"

Answer (score 0):

sudden_appearance already provided a good answer.
In case you don't like regex too much you can use this code instead:

```
new_lines = []
with open('test_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    c = 1
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == '>':
            after_dash = line.split('_',1)[1]
            new_line = '>' + str(c) + '_' + after_dash
            c += 1
            new_lines.append(new_line)
        else:
            new_lines.append(line)
        
with open('test_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(new_lines)
```

Also you can have a look at [this split tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) for more information about how to use split.

Comment: Thank you sudden_appearence and @Blupper, both the codes solved my problem

Comment: @AakifRehman You are most welcome. Feel free to accept one of the answers and/or up-vote both of them.

Comment: my low reputation count does not allow me to do so.